# If the nth element of a list passes a condition, how do I select the nth element of another list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

If the nth element of `pair_length` passes a condition, then I want to write to an output file the nth elements of `x_cords`, `y_cords`, and `pair_num`. For example, if the 3rd element of the `pair_length` list passes the condition `length <= average_pair_length():`, then I want to select the 3rd elements of `x_cords`, `y_cords`, and `pair_num` lists so I can write them to an output file. I tried using the filter() function but it did not return what I wanted.
Here is my code:

```
pair_length = []
pair_nums = []
x_cords = []
y_cords = []
for line in islice(data, 1, None):
    fields = line.split("   ")
    pair_num = float(fields[0])
    pair_nums.append(pair_num)
    x_cord = float(fields[1])
    x_cords.append(x_cord)
    y_cord = float(fields[2])
    y_cords.append(y_cord)
    vector_length = sqrt(x_cord**2 + y_cord**2)
    pair_length.append(vector_length)

def average_pair_length():
    average = mean(pair_length)
    return average

index = 0
for index, length in enumerate(pair_length):
    if length <= average_pair_length():
    #this is where I want to find the nth element of pair_length so I can find the nth elements in the other lists
```

Comment: You have `index` in your for loop, why don't you use it to index the other lists?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help, can you please clarify? Basically, every element of pair_length corresponds to elements in the other lists. Every time an element of pair_length passes the condition, I want to select the corresponding elements.

Comment: for example, `pair_nums[index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `index` to determine which element it is in the array

```
for index, length in enumerate(pair_length): # index tells you which element it is
    if length <= average_pair_length():
        x, y, pair_num = x_cords[index], y_cords[index], pair_nums[index]
        print(x, y, pair_num) 
        # Do what you want to do with the matching x, y, and pair_num here
```

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you